How do I write a good movie or TV show identification answer?
The purpose of this meta post is to give us a single page to link users to for guidance on crafting a good movie or TV show identification answer, serving as a companion to our "Tips for asking Movie/TV Identification questions" meta post.
Answering identification questions can be tricky, and users could benefit from some guidance on how to provide the most helpful responses. We often see comments asking answerers to include more details, which highlights the need for a clear set of guidelines.
What advice would you offer on how to write a good movie or TV show identification answer?
(This meta post draws inspiration from a similar meta post on our sister site, Science Fiction & Fantasy SE: "How to write a good story-ID answer?")

Here are some pointers to keep in mind when answering movie or TV show ID questions:

Include key details:

Provide the title of the movie or TV show.
Include the release year.
Include a synopsis, highlighting elements that match the asker’s description.
Include links to IMDb pages or other reliable references (such as Rotten Tomatoes) that can offer more information about your answer.
Add a link to the trailer (or full content), if available.


Match the question:

Address as many points from the original question as possible.
If the asker mentioned a plot point, specific scene, character trait, etc., make sure to highlight how your suggestion fits (or doesn’t fit) that description.
If you can find a clip or image of the scene the asker described, include it.


Explain your reasoning:

If you’re not 100% certain, explain why you think your answer is likely a match. This shows your thought process and can help the asker make connections.


Be open to feedback.

If the asker responds with more details or clarifications, be ready to adjust your answer or provide additional information.



Remember, a well-crafted answer not only helps the person asking the question but also contributes to our community’s knowledge base. So, take a little extra time to make your identification answers as informative and helpful as possible!
(This post borrows some ideas from a similar guide on our sister site, Science Fiction and Fantasy SE. "How to write a good story-ID answer?")
